# Strange shadow artifacts in Unity 5.1

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need a help of the experts.
There is a strange shadow artifact inside Unity 5.1

- Creating a new light;
- Creating a new plane;
- Creating a new casting the shadow object;
- Changing the bias and normal bias;
- Turning off all the image effects;
- Switching GI to non-directional mode with higher atlas size.
  None of the above helped.

Do you know, what is the problem? How can I fix it? Any tricks?

Illustration of the artifact:
[image: illustration]

Comment: Hi lebrokholic, in your screenshot people can see that big ground shadow, and you detailed what didn't work out to get rid of it. I believe it will be easier to understand the problem if you also detail which lights are being used and all other elements that you are currently using that may influence shadows. (I am not familiar with unity, but people voted that your question "should be improved")

Comment: The shadow on the ground is casted by the horse.
In addition, I used only one standard directional light. If I correct the values of bias to 0.08 and normal bias to 0, the result looks better compared to the screenshot, but actually it is a huge glitching black spot.
Moreover, I have disabled all the game objects except the light, standard plane and standard cube. The same situation

Comment: If I create a new scene and add a standard plane with a standard cube, the artifact remains. Seems like it is connected with the project settings, but I did not change anything there.

Comment: If I create a new scene inside another project and simulate the described situation, everything looks great. Maybe there is a possibility of reseting project settings? The question is still open.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Edit->Project Settings -> Player

Change color space from Gamma to Linear

Change Rending Path from Defferd to Forward (You can change it back later)

Restart project.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions that I've used is:

- to create a new project;
- to import all the necessary standard assets;
- to import all the files from "Assets" folder without scene files
  (lightmap and etc.);
- to ignore project settings, temporary files and etc. (only the
  "Assets" folder)